# ¿Por qué obtengo "#INF00" como salida al calcular el número e?

Tags: c

El codigo pide calcular el numero `e` segun el sumatorio de (`1/n!`) empezando n en 0 y acabando en `1e6`.

El error que me aparece es cuando se imprime por pantalla el resultado me aparece:

> 1.#INF00

Este es mi código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n=1e6,c;
    double e=1;
    double i_f;
    for(c=1;c<=n;c++)
    {
        i_f=i_f*c;
        e=e+i_f;
    }
    printf("\nEl valor aproximado de e es: %lf", e);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inicializa `i_f`:

```
double i_f=¿?; /* no puedo decidir el valor de inicio por ti */
```

Si no lo haces tendrá basura (un valor aleatorio) y eso te impedirá conseguir un resultado correcto.

Aun así ya te adelanto que cuidado con el valor que le asignas... con 0 te devolverá 1 y con prácticamente cualquier otro el resultado que comentas... ¿por qué?

Esa etiqueta quiere decir que en algún momento se ha alcanzado un valor tan grande (o pequeño) que no puede ser representado por la variable. Llegados a este punto en la variable se guarda un valor especial que representa al *infinito*... no es más que un aviso de que has desbordado la variable.

¿pero... por qué da infinito?

La explicación se encuentra en esta línea:

```
i_f=i_f*c;
```

Teniendo en cuenta que `c` se mueve en el intervalo (1,1e6) y que no has inicializado `i_f`, existe la posibilidad de que de un número inmenso... asumimos que tiende a infinito. Así pues:

```
c! = INF;
i_f * c! = i_f * INF = INF
```

También puede suceder que los 3 primeros bytes del double acaben con el valor `7ff`, que es la etiqueta que se suele utilizar para definir el número infinito... es complicado pero no imposible.

¿y entonces?

El enunciado dice:

> calcular el numero e segun el sumatorio de (1/n!)

Fíjate que no te están pidiendo que calcules la serie para (n!) sino para (1/n!)... que no es lo mismo:

- desarrollo n! = 1! * 2! * 3! * 4! * ... * n! -> número muy grande
- desarrollo 1/n! = 1/1! * 1/2! * 1/3! * ... * 1/n! -> número razonable

Es decir:

```
int main()
{
    int n=1e6;
    double e=1;
    double i_f = 1;
    for(int c=1;c<=n;c++)
    {
        i_f *= c;
        e+=1.0/i_f;
    }
    printf("\nEl valor aproximado de e es: %lf", e);
    return 0;
}
```

A mi este código me devuelve

```
El valor aproximado de e es: 2.718282
```

Lo cual me parece una aproximación bastante razonable

Comment: Duda por desconocimiento de [tag:c]: Por qué no inicializar `i_f` le asigna un valor aleatorio?

Comment: @lois6b Porque al declarar una variable simplemente se le asigna una posición de memoria... junto con el valor que tenía esa posición de memoria => basura. En lenguajes con *objetos* (caso de C++, Java, ...) hay elementos que ya incorporan rutinas para inicializar esa memoria, pero en C te lo tienes que currar todo tu.

Comment: gracias por la explicación